# Bind formula for changes in store

Tags: extjs, mvvm, bind, formula, store

I am have formula and want execute it when store in this `viewModel` is `changeData`.

When I do this, the formula does not work when data in store changed

```
stores: {

    currentStore: {
        extend: 'Ext.store.MyStore',
        trackRemoved: false
    },
    },
    formulas: {

    'executeWhenStoreChange': {
        bind: '{currentStore}',

        get: function () {
           console.log('store change')
    },
```

Comment: I would get your grammar fixed for you, if I only understood what you are trying to tell us.

Comment: May be you are looking for an event `datachanged` in store. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-datachanged

Comment: i am want after data in store change, call formula  'executeWhenStoreChange', maybe i can bind to store this formula ?

Comment: I just answered an almost identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892363/how-to-bind-correctly-a-formula-with-a-store-in-sencha-extjs-v6/42448638#42448638

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to fire a function when data changed I would use a `datachanged` listener to the store(s) you want the event to fire on.

```
    currentStore: {
        listeners: {
            datachanged: function(store, eOpts) {
                console.log('store change');
            }
        }
    },
```

If you want it for all stores just reference the function in each `datachanged` listener

```
    currentStoreA: {
        listeners: {
            datachanged: 'onStoreDataChangeD'
        }
    },
    currentStoreB: {
        listeners: {
            datachanged: 'onStoreDataChangeD'
        }
    },
```

Then in the view controller:

```
    onStoreDataChangeD: function(store, eOpts) {
    console.log('store changed');
}
```